# Add member to marketing list in CRM 2011 plugin

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I hope there is someone who can help me out here. I have found an article which gives you the short piece of code to add Add Multiple Entities (Members) to a Marketing List. So far so good. I'm coming across this problem. I have a custom lookup field which gets another marketing list (has contacts, accounts or leads) inside the marketing member list. Now I need to migrate (add) those members into my new marketing list. The code I have:

```
  1. AddListMembersListRequest request = new AddListMembersListRequest();
  2. request.ListId = Origmarketing_List_Id.Id;  
  3. request.MemberIds = new Guid[1];
  4. request.MemberIds[0] = guid;
  5. AddListMembersListResponse resp = (AddListMembersListResponse)service.Execute(request);
```

Line 2 is the ID I get from the EntityReference(Look Up field getting another Marketing List), now the third and fourth line I'm setting is something I'm really confused about but still I'm sure I'm going right here because I'm setting it to the listmemberid. In this example I just had one cause I wanted to try out how it works. The guid in line 4 bdw gets the right value, it is declared at the top of my code(and I have output it on another field just to check it grabs the right value). Also can someone please show how you would do this when you want to add multiple entities? Thanks. I'm registering my plugin on pre-operation(Create). And the plugin itself doesn't fire any errors, but it just doesn't seem to add any members on my new list. I would really much appreciate if somone could help me out here. Thank You Really Much in Advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, change event to post-operation, because you don't have the GUID of created entity yet, as a matter of fact you dont have the entity itself as well that's why it's called pre-operation.
To add multiple entities try pass a GUIDs array like in code bellow:

```
    // Setup the CrmConnection and OrganizationService instances
    CrmConnectionInstance = new CrmConnection(ConfigurationConstants.CrmConnectionName);
OrgServiceInstance = new OrganizationService(CrmConnectionInstance);
    // Create the marketing list 
    Guid NewMarketingListId = Guid.Empty; 
    Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity CurrentList = new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity(MarketingListConstants.MarketingListEntityName); 
    CurrentList[MarketingListConstants.MarketingListTypeAttribute] = false; 
    CurrentList[MarketingListConstants.ListNameAttribute] = "NameOfList"; 
    // For contacts, a value of 2 should be used. 
    CurrentList[MarketingListConstants.CreatedFromCodeAttribute] = new OptionSetValue(2); 
    // Actually create the list 
    NewMarketingListId = OrgServiceInstance.Create(CurrentList); 
    // Use the AddListMembersListRequest to add the members to the list 
    List<Guid> MemberListIds = new List<Guid>(); 
    // Now you'll need to add the Guids for each member to the list  
    // I'm leaving that part out as adding values to a list is very basic. 
    AddListMembersListRequest AddMemberRequest = new AddListMembersListRequest(); 
    AddMemberRequest.ListId = NewMarketingListId; 
    AddMemberRequest.MemberIds = memberIds.ToArray(); 
    // Use AddListMembersListReponse to get information about the request execution 
    AddListMembersListResponse AddMemberResponse = OrgServiceInstance.Execute(AddMemberRequest) as AddListMembersListResponse;
```

Comment: Hi Grigory, thank you very much for your solution worked fine for me :-). Just to let you know I was making a really stupid mistake I was grabbing the listmemberid Guid instead of the entityid Guid that's why my records never got inserted, but now its working fine. Thanks again, really much appreciate your effort.